# MOSFET current direction

Tags: transistors, mosfet, current, fet

What is the direction of conventional current in a N-Channel MOSFET? What I think is it's from Drain to Source **inside** the transistor which means **externally**(in the external circuit) it will be the opposite (S to D) is that true? And when I search for the direction of current in a specific transistor do people talk about the **internal** (inside the transistor) or the **external** current? Because they (internal and external directions) are always the opposite of each other.

Also there is a way to know the current direction which is from the symbols. So do the arrows in the symbols represent the external or internal current? What I think is that they represent the internal but I'm not sure and I need confirmation please.

And one last question; why is the current direction imposed, can't we use a transistor in its opposite current direction? Are MOSFETs and other transistors unidirectional or not?

Comment: It depends on the circuit surrounding the FET. Can you draw a diagram?

Comment: Small-signal current can go in either direction once the FET is properly biased

Comment: The arrows in the schematic symbols for bipolar transistors and most diodes point in the direction of conventional current flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the direction of conventional current in a N-Channel MOSFET? What I think is it's from Drain to Source inside the transistor

Conventional current flows from positive to negative, except inside of power sources such as batteries, etc. When an N-Channel enhancement MOSFET has it's drain more positive than its source, and the gate is sufficiently more positive than the source, then conventional current will flow from the drain to the source.

However, it is not always the case that the drain of an N-Channel (enhancement) MOSFET is more positive than the source. Sometimes it is the other way around. This happens more often than you might think. It often happens when the MOSFET is switching an inductive load.

When the source of an N-Channel enhancement MOSFET is more positive than the drain, conventional current may flow from source to drain. Due to the way MOSFETs are constructed, there is what is called a "body diode" between source and drain. In an N-Channel enhancement MOSFET that body diode is forward biased if the source is more positive than the drain. So, if that diode is sufficiently forward biased, it will conduct. In addition, if the gate is sufficiently positive with respect to the source, the MOSFET channel will conduct. Usually, when the channel conducts there is less of a voltage drop than when the body diode is carrying all the current. Often P-channel enhancement MOSFETs are used in this mode to provide reverse polarity protection circuits with very low voltage drop. But aside from these "exceptions", the standard "on" mode of an N-channel enhancement MOSFET has the gate and drain more positive than the source, and conventional current is flowing from the drain to the source within the MOSFET.

> which means externally(in the external circuit) it will be the opposite (S to D) is that true?

Yes, to make a complete circuit, current needs to flow in the same direction around one or more loops. If conventional current is flowing from Drain to Source within the MOSFET, it is flowing outside of the MOSFET from the source pin the drain pin (usually through some power supply) to complete the loop.

> And when I search for the direction of current in a specific transistor do people talk about the internal (inside the transistor) or the external current? Because they (internal and external directions) are always the opposite of each other.

When people speak of the direction of current **in** a component, they mean **in** that component, i.e. internally.

> Also there is a way to know the current direction which is from the symbols. So do the arrows in the symbols represent the external or internal current? What I think is that they represent the internal but I'm not sure and I need confirmation please.

Yes, in MOSFET symbols, the direction of the arrow head indicates the polarity of the MOSFET -- N-Channel or P-Channel. Unfortunately, there are multiple symbols used for MOSFETs, typically one for discrete MOSFETs and another for MOSFETs within an integrated circuit.

For the symbol usually used for discrete MOSFETs if the source has an arrow-head pointing toward the gate, then it is an N-channel MOSFET. If it has an arrow-head that points away from the gate, then it is P-channel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGobQT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the symbol typically used for MOSFETs within an integrated circuit, the rule is the opposite. If the arrow-head points toward the base, the MOSFET is P-Channel, and if it points away from the base, it is N-Channel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKp6OS.png)</sup>

Be aware that in a Bipolar Junction Transistor (BJT), if the arrow-head points toward the base, then the transistor is PNP, and if it points away from the base it is NPN.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP5uFL.png)</sup>

> And one last question; why is the current direction imposed, can't we use a transistor in its opposite current direction? Are MOSFETs and other transistors unidirectional or not?

Most, but not all, transistors are asymmetric. For MOSFETs, the asymmetry comes about through the direction of the body diode. If a (three terminal) MOSFET is reversed in a circuit, it will simply not behave correctly. The asymmetry in BJTs arise from the lighter doping (and usually larger size) of collectors vs emitters. The one type of transistor that is commonly not asymmetric is the Junction Field Effect Transistor (J-FET). Many J-FETs can be operated with their source and drain reversed without any noticeable change in characteristics.